# Enum of long values in C#

Tags: c#, enums

Why does this declaration,

```
public enum ECountry : long
{
    None,
    Canada,
    UnitedStates
}
```

require a cast for any of its values?

```
long ID = ECountry.Canada;
// Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'ECountry' to 'long'.
// An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

And is there a way to get a long value directly from the enum, besides casting?

This would not work either, for example:

```
public enum ECountry : long
{
    None = 0L,
    Canada = 1L,
    UnitedStates=2L
}
```

Comment: Why would you ever need to have more than ~4 billion enumerated values?

Comment: @Yuck : I wanted to store IDs, and keep type consistency between those enums and the data structures that holds those. It picked my curiosity while testing different way to achieve this :)

Comment: @Yuck: It's not the quantity of enumerated values, but the actual value held in that enum. I don't know why your comment is being upvoted at least 4 times because it does not make sense.

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you get for `long ID = ECountry.Canada`?

Comment: You're unlikely to want more than 4 billion enumerated values, but you might want more than 32 flags.

Comment: @Yuck, the enumeriation may represent large numbers values from other systems. (Although it doesn't in the example given).

Comment: @Code Monkey: Good point, +1 on your answer.

Comment: @Yuck I don't think his point is good at all. The main reason you can change the underlying type of an `enum` is to support `Flags` enumerations that have more than 32 items. You *can* use it to store random `long` values as well, but that's less common and kind of a bad idea.

Comment: I think it should probably better to implement a class of CountryID so you can abstract enum glitches, avoid "casts" and make it more expansible.

Comment: I enjoy the fact that stevemegson's comment has 32 upvotes

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The issue is *not* that the underlying type is still `int`. It's `long`, and you can assign `long` values to the members. However, you can *never* just assign an `enum` value to an integral type without a cast. This should work:

```
public enum ECountry : long
{
    None,
    Canada,
    UnitedStates = (long)int.MaxValue + 1;
}

// val will be equal to the *long* value int.MaxValue + 1
long val = (long)ECountry.UnitedStates;
```

Comment: "However, you can never just assign an enum value to an integral type without a cast." - Can the reason be explained, please?

Comment: @CosmicGiant: Because enums are not supposed to have "meaningful" values, they should just support some ordering.  If you want to perform arithmetics, then you should use constants.

Answer (score 10):

The default underlying type of `enum` is `int`. An `enum` can be any integral type except `char`.

If you want it to be `long`, you can do something like this:

```
// Using long enumerators
using System;
public class EnumTest 
{
    enum Range :long {Max = 2147483648L, Min = 255L};
    static void Main() 
    {
        long x = (long)Range.Max;
        long y = (long)Range.Min;
        Console.WriteLine("Max = {0}", x);
        Console.WriteLine("Min = {0}", y);
    }
}
```

The cast is what is important here. And as @dlev says, the purpose of using `long` in an `enum` is to support a large number of flags (more than 32 since 2^32 is 4294967296 and a `long` can hold more than 2^32).

Answer (score 7):

You **must** cast an enum to get a value from it or it will remain an `enum` type.

Answer (score 2):

[From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum#example-1):

In this example, the base-type option is used to declare an enum whose members are of the type long. Notice that even though the underlying type of the enumeration is long, the enumeration members must still be explicitly converted to type long using a cast.

```
// keyword_enum2.cs
// Using long enumerators
using System;
public class EnumTest
{
    enum Range :long {Max = 2147483648L, Min = 255L};
    static void Main()
    {
        long x = (long)Range.Max;
        long y = (long)Range.Min;
        Console.WriteLine("Max = {0}", x);
        Console.WriteLine("Min = {0}", y);
    }
}
```

> Output
>
> Max = 2147483648 Min = 255

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you have got to cast.

The MSDN article says:

> "However, an explicit cast is needed to convert from enum type to an integral type" (either int or long)

You can check it out:

*[Enumeration types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)*