# How to define enum length different types

Tags: c#

I must define to new enums and enums can be different length and type. How can I define them?

For example:

```
F0092 = binary and 8 digits
F0093 = number and 16 digits
```

Comment: An [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sbbt4032.aspx) is an integer type. You can't specify how large of an integer is will be.

Comment: @jp2code in your link : `Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char`. But still i assume that you can't use different types in one enum

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? can you rephrase the question? Also please include a use-case or something.

Comment: @jp2code you are incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inherit like a base class:

```
public enum IntEnum : int
{
    A,
}

public enum ShortEnum : short
{
    A,
}

public enum ByteEnum : byte
{
    A,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a complete idea, How to do this. @moho is right. For example Please visit this:

[Enum data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093360/c-sharp-enum-of-long-values)